$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^k}{2^n}$ is natural for all $k$
Let $$a_k=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^k}{2^n}.$$ Prove that for any $k\in\mathbb{N},$ $a_k\in\mathbb{N}$. 
I've got this problem which i cannot really tie up, the gist of my proof is as follows:
I went for an induction proof, I am going to show the result for $k=1$ and then derive the rest. ,
$$a_1=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{n}{2^n}$$
Let's define the linear application $\tau$ which takes a function $f(x)$, derives it and then evalueates it at $x=1$. if we were to apply $\tau$ to $x^n$ we would obtain: $$\tau(x^n)=nx^n|_{x=1}=n$$
So i can write the sum as:
$$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\tau(x^n)}{2^n}=\tau(\sum_{n\geq1}(\frac{x}{2})^n)=\tau(\frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{2}})=\frac{1}{(2-x)^2}\bigg|_{x=1}=1.$$
Where tthe first $"="$ is for the linearity of $\tau$ and the second one is the geometric series expansion. 
Ok, let's not assume we solved the case $k$ and we want to solve the case $k+1$. 
I used the same trick but with the caveat that i have to find a way to write $n^k$ as composition of linear applications. We can write:
$$n^2=n(n-1)+n=\tau^2(x^n)+\tau(x^n)$$ Since i can do this for any power of $n$ that i want i always have a way, though a bit convuluted, to write $n^k$ as a combination of powers of $\tau$. At this point i finish the proof:
$$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{n^{k+1}}{2^n}=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\tau(x^{k+1})}{2^n}$$ At this point i got stuck, i'm not sure how to obtain back the inductive hypotesis without breaking the whole thing apart. Thanks in advance.

The answer by Mark is quite easy to understand, yet I also quite like the approach by F.Marin here showing an induction with integer coefficients therefore the next term should be integer too --> https://math.stackexchange.com/a/530619/399263

Induction is a good idea, but I'd also use differentiating power series term by term. We know that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$ for $|x|<1$. If we differentiate term by term we get:
$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^{n-1}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}.$
Multiplying by $x$ gives $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^n=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$. Differentiating again gives:
$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2x^{n-1}=\frac{1+x}{(1-x)^3}.$
And if we multiply by $x$ then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2x^n=\frac{x+x^2}{(1-x)^3}$. At this point we can already guess how it goes. By induction, prove that:
$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}n^kx^n=\frac{p(x)}{(1-x)^{k+1}},$
where $p(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients of degree at most $k$. The identity is true for all $|x|<1$. Now, if we substitute $x=\frac{1}{2}$:
$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^k}{2^n}=\frac{p(\frac{1}{2})}{(\frac{1}{2})^{k+1}}=2^{k+1}p(\frac{1}{2}).$
And since $p$ is of degree at most $k$, the result is indeed an integer.

This is great! thank you!

Observe that with Stirling set numbers
$$\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{n^k}{2^n}
= k! [z^k] \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{1}{2^n} \exp(nz)
\\ = k! [z^k] \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{1}{2^n}
\sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} (\exp(z)-1)^q
\\ = \sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{1}{2^n}
\sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} q! {k\brace q}.$$
Here we have used that with $k\ge 1$ the contribution from $n=0$ is
zero. Continuing
$$\sum_{q\ge 0} q! {k\brace q}
\sum_{n\ge q} {n\choose q} \frac{1}{2^n}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^k q! {k\brace q} \frac{1}{2^q}
\sum_{n\ge 0} {n+q\choose q} \frac{1}{2^n}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^k q! {k\brace q} \frac{1}{2^q}
\frac{1}{(1-1/2)^{q+1}}
= 2 \sum_{q=0}^k q! {k\brace q}.$$
This is an integer by inspection. The case $k=0$ is immediate, giving
$1/2 \times 1/(1-1/2) = 1.$
